# Thymeleaf template parsing error

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I get parsing error when I try to load `localhost:8080/`.

I can't find any errors in my template, so why have I this mistake?

#### Error

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Apr 20 16:59:56 EEST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception parsing document: template="index", line 26 - column 3
```

#### Template (HTML)

```jsp
<tr th:each="customer : ${customers}">
    <td th:text="${customer.identity}">001</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.name}">Name</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.address}">Address</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.age}">Age</td>
</tr>
```

#### View (Class)

```java
public String mainPage(Model model){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
    PersonJDBCTemplate personJDBCTemplate = (PersonJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("personJDBCTemplate");
    List<Person> persons = personJDBCTemplate.getAllPersons();
    model.addAttribute("customers", persons);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: Adding the error message to your question would help.

Comment: Actually I added, but I'm not sure there's smth helpful.

Comment: I really hope that this isn't production code! You shouldn't be creating an application context for the sake of getting a bean, that is what dependency injection is for. Also you seem to be using Spring Boot so that makes it even weirder on why you are even trying to do so. Regarding your template what is on **line 26 - column 3**

Comment: Have you tried [googling the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=This+application+has+no+explicit+mapping+for+%2Ferror%2C+so+you+are+seeing+this+as+a+fallback.)?

Comment: Yeap, it isn't production code. I'll rewrite it, thank you for noticing this. on line 26 is end of my html template.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes, I tried, but actually I can't find where exactly mistake in my template.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understood and had fixed one of my mistakes, but  I'm still don't understand what's wrong with template. Thank you.

Comment: Is your template generating valid html? Is it closed properly? This is only a snippet and doesn't have html, head or body tags...

Comment: can you post your full HTML template?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**May be** you are **missing a closing tag** somewhere. I have no idea what you have in the HTML template, unless you post the complete code.

But replace your current file with this template. And it should work. Then you can add your missing codes to it.

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en"></head>
<body>
<tr th:each="customer : ${customers}">
    <td th:text="${customer.identity}">001</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.name}">Name</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.address}">Address</td>
    <td th:text="${customer.age}">Age</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, make sure that self-closing tags like `<meta>` and `<img>` are also closed. Thymeleaf can only handle valid XML

Answer (score 0):

*Your template name may be misspelled!*

This just bit me in the butt.  All closing tags were verified via online tool, but that won't help you when the template engine name you define in your controller doesn't exactly match with the actual file name.

**Note** that this answer addresses a possible, but not highly probable explanation for the error.  It is more for people coming in from search; the specific reasons that lead the OP to post are most likely caused by the lack of closing tag.  However, who knows?  The controller code was not included.